# SELECT inside stored proc doesn't work correctly whereas outside it does

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have a simple database as follows in mysql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MEDIAVEND.ITEMDETAILS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MEDIAVEND.ITEMDETAILS (
    ItemID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ITEMTYPE ENUM('MUSIC', 'MOVIE', 'GAME') NOT NULL,
    ITEMMEDIATYPE ENUM('CD', 'DVD', 'BLURAY') NOT NULL,
    ITEMNAME CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ITEMDESCRIPTION CHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ITEMCOUNT BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MACHINEID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ITEMID)
);

INSERT INTO MEDIAVEND.ITEMDETAILS VALUES 
    (1,'MUSIC','CD','ALBUM 1','SOME DESCRIPTION OF 1',100,1),
    (2,'MUSIC','CD','ALBUM 2','SOME DESCRIPTION OF 2',20,1),
    (3,'MOVIE','DVD','MOVIE 1','SOME DESCRIPTION OF 1',30,1),
    (4,'MOVIE','BLURAY','MOVIE 2','SOME DESCRIPTION OF 2',40,1),
    (5,'GAME','DVD','GAME 1','SOME DESCRIPTION OF 1',50,1),
    (6,'GAME','BLURAY','GAME 2','SOME DESCRIPTION OF 2',60,1);
```

and a stored proc as :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `info_ItemType`(in itemType char(10))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM MEDIAVEND.ITEMDETAILS WHERE ITEMTYPE= itemType;
END
```

so when i call following i see different results.

```
select * from mediavend.itemdetails where itemType='MUSIC';
```

-- 2 rows returned

```
call mediavend.info_ItemType('MUSIC');
```

-- 6 rows returned

i am really baffled, pardon me if it is a silly mistake, but i have gone through lots of questions and don't see any relevant to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your input parameter since it has the same name as the column.

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `info_ItemType`(in itemType_Param char(10))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM MEDIAVEND.ITEMDETAILS 
    WHERE ITEMTYPE = itemType_Param;
END
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is not case sensitive, so when you say `where ITEMTYPE = itemType`, you're looking for where the column is equal to itself, hence all rows are returned.

You need to use a unique parameter name.

Comment: wow, case sensitivity !will never forget that about mysql. Thank you.